# How can I determine what constitutes valid nesting of tags in Apache Trinidad Faces?

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces, nested, oracle-adf

I have a complex application that contains a mix of JSF and Apache MyFaces. In any case, I'm getting a runtime ServletException about a ConvertNumberTag () that's invalidly-nested (currently, it's under a tr:outputText tag).

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to tell what is valid and invalid nesting. The Apache MyFaces site doesn't provide this information.

Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error, of course~!